# Send Values to BaseHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python

I am creating a simple web server using HTTPServer and BaseHTTPRequestHandler in Python. Here is what I have so far:

```
from handler import Handler #my BaseHTTPRequestHandler

def run(self):
    httpd = HTTPServer(('', 7214), Handler)
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    httpd.server_close()
```

I want to set the base path for the Handler to serve files from, but I am not sure how to do that since it hasn't been instantiated yet? I have a feeling that this is really easy/obvious, but I cannot think how to do it. I know I can do it inside of the Handler class, but I want to do it from here if possible, since all of my configurations are read here.

Comment: You want to serve files from a directory? SimpleHTTPServer does that for you already by default...

Comment: I guess I could have used `SimpleHTTPServer`/`SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`, but I think my question is still valid for this class as well. How do I tell `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` to use a specific directory and not just the current directory. I guess I didn't make that super clear.

Comment: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` will serve files from the CWD if you need. Just trying to make your job easy. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one wanted to answer your question...

Just replace the part in the code with the comment "yourpath".

```
import os
import posixpath
import socket
import urllib
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler


class MyFileHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def translate_path(self, path):
        """Translate a /-separated PATH to the local filename syntax.

        Components that mean special things to the local file system
        (e.g. drive or directory names) are ignored.  (XXX They should
        probably be diagnosed.)

        """
        # abandon query parameters
        path = path.split('?',1)[0]
        path = path.split('#',1)[0]
        path = posixpath.normpath(urllib.unquote(path))
        words = path.split('/')
        words = filter(None, words)
        path = '/' # yourpath
        for word in words:
            drive, word = os.path.splitdrive(word)
            head, word = os.path.split(word)
            if word in (os.curdir, os.pardir): continue
            path = os.path.join(path, word)
        return path

def run():
    try:
        httpd = HTTPServer(('', 7214), MyFileHandler)
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    except socket.error as e:
        print e
    else:
        httpd.server_close()
```